# Array Loop - get the first value into a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have an array,  and I want to get the first value into a foreach loop.  then send that value to a function.

- This does not work

  ```
  foreach ($frequency as $i) {        
     showphp_AlexVortaro (getphp_AlexVortaro ($frequency[$i]));
     showphp_Smartfm(getphp_Smartfm($frequency[$i]));        
  }
  ```

Comment: I have problems to understand the problem. Do you want to get *only* the *first* value of the array and send it to a function or do you want to send *every* value to a function?

Comment: As nobody is linking to it: Documentation of the `foreach` control structure: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you mean to use the current 'exposed' offset as your functions' arguments:

```
foreach($frequency as $i) {        
   showphp_AlexVortaro (getphp_AlexVortaro($i));
   showphp_Smartfm(getphp_Smartfm($i));        
}
```

or:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($frequencies); $i++) {        
   showphp_AlexVortaro(getphp_AlexVortaro($frequencies[$i]));
   showphp_Smartfm($frequencies[$i]);        
}
```

Comment: What if it ia associated array?

Comment: @streetparade, I'm assuming that `$frequencies` refers to a numerically indexed array of floats (or strings), e.g.  96.5 or '96.5' (I arrived at that assumption by assuming that `getphp_Smartfm` returns something radio related based on a given frequency).

Answer (score 2):

$i is the value of your array in the foreach loop. Instead of sending $frequency[$i] you must use '$i'.

If you want to fetch the keys use the following construction:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: Ok the Comment // Do something is funny, 
i think there should be a control statement am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `current();` function would return the first value;

```
echo current($array);
```